# Dependency Resolution of Interface by Name in Prism WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependencies, unity-container, prism

I have a requirement where I need 3 instances of ZmqService shared among different pages of the application. For this, I have registered the IZmqService interface like below with individual names :-

```
container.RegisterInstance<IZmqService>("liveViewCaptureService", new ZmqService());
container.RegisterInstance<IZmqService>("faceMatchCaptureService", new ZmqService());
container.RegisterInstance<IZmqService>("captureServiceTrigger", new ZmqService());
```

Now, for my viewModels I have resolved like this :-

```
IZmqService liveViewCaptureService = container.Resolve<IZmqService>("liveViewCaptureService");
IZmqService faceMatchCaptureService = container.Resolve<IZmqService>("faceMatchCaptureService");
IZmqService captureServiceTrigger = container.Resolve<IZmqService>("captureServiceTrigger");

container.RegisterType<IManualVerificationPageViewModel, ManualVerificationPageViewModel>(
               new PerResolveLifetimeManager(),
               new InjectionConstructor(
                   new InjectionParameter<IRegionManager>(container.Resolve<IRegionManager>()),
                   new InjectionParameter<IEventAggregator>(container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>()),
                   new InjectionParameter<IDialogService>(container.Resolve<IDialogService>()),
                   new InjectionParameter<ICaptureService>(container.Resolve<ICaptureService>()),
                   new InjectionParameter<IAppConfiguration>(container.Resolve<IAppConfiguration>()),
                   new InjectionParameter<IMessageQueueService>(container.Resolve<IMessageQueueService>()),
                   new InjectionParameter(liveViewCaptureService),
                   new InjectionParameter(faceMatchCaptureService)
                   )
               );
```

In my XAML, I have set `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`

The constructor of my view model is :-

```
public ManualVerificationPageViewModel(
            IRegionManager regionManager,
            IEventAggregator eventAggregator,
            IDialogService dialogService,
            ICaptureService captureService,
            IAppConfiguration appConfiguration,
            IMessageQueueService messageQueueService,
            IZmqService liveViewCaptureService,
            IZmqService faceMatchCaptureService
            )
        {
            _regionManager = regionManager;
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            _dialogService = dialogService;
            _captureService = captureService;
            _appConfiguration = appConfiguration;
            _messageQueueService = messageQueueService;

            _liveViewCaptureService = liveViewCaptureService;
            _faceMatchCaptureService = faceMatchCaptureService;

            SelectIdentityCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoSelectIdentity);
            VerifyCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoVerify, CanVerify)
                .ObservesProperty(() => SelectedIdentityType)
                .ObservesProperty(() => IdentityNumber);

            CancelCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoCancel);
            RecaptureCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoRecapture);
        }
```

If I try to resolve the ViewModel in my App.xaml.cs as below,

```
IManualVerificationPageViewModel vm = container.Resolve<IManualVerificationPageViewModel>();
```

I get a valid ViewModel. But when AutoWire happens in my page, it gives the below error :-

```
ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 'NEC.AAI.EGate.Checkin.ViewModels.ManualVerificationPageViewModel', name = '(none)'.
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, NEC.AAI.EGate.Services.IZmqService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was: 
  Resolving NEC.AAI.EGate.Checkin.ViewModels.ManualVerificationPageViewModel,(none)
  Resolving parameter 'liveViewCaptureService' of constructor NEC.AAI.EGate.Checkin.ViewModels.ManualVerificationPageViewModel(Prism.Regions.IRegionManager regionManager, Prism.Events.IEventAggregator eventAggregator, NEC.AAI.EGate.UI.Common.Services.IDialogService dialogService, NEC.AAI.EGate.Services.ICaptureService captureService, NEC.AAI.EGate.Services.IAppConfiguration appConfiguration, NEC.AAI.EGate.Services.MessageQueue.IMessageQueueService messageQueueService, NEC.AAI.EGate.Services.IZmqService liveViewCaptureService, NEC.AAI.EGate.Services.IZmqService faceMatchCaptureService)
    Resolving NEC.AAI.EGate.Services.IZmqService,(none)
```

AutoWire works fine if I am registering a type of IZmqService like this :-

```
IZmqService liveViewCaptureService = container.Resolve<IZmqService>("liveViewCaptureService");
IZmqService faceMatchCaptureService = container.Resolve<IZmqService>("faceMatchCaptureService");
IZmqService captureServiceTrigger = container.Resolve<IZmqService>("captureServiceTrigger");

container.RegisterType<IZmqService, ZmqService>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

BUT this creates a new instance of IZmqService for every constructor parameter instead of using the registered types.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I got the resolution.

What I was doing was register my interface with the view model and there was no linking between the AutoWireViewModel and the interface.

All I had to do is change it to :-

```
container.RegisterType<ManualVerificationPageViewModel>(
                   new PerResolveLifetimeManager(),
                   new InjectionConstructor(
                       new InjectionParameter<IRegionManager>(container.Resolve<IRegionManager>()),
                       new InjectionParameter<IEventAggregator>(container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>()),
                       new InjectionParameter<IDialogService>(container.Resolve<IDialogService>()),
                       new InjectionParameter<ICaptureService>(container.Resolve<ICaptureService>()),
                       new InjectionParameter<IAppConfiguration>(container.Resolve<IAppConfiguration>()),
                       new InjectionParameter<IMessageQueueService>(container.Resolve<IMessageQueueService>()),
                       new InjectionParameter(container.Resolve<IZmqService>("liveViewCaptureService")),
                       new InjectionParameter(container.Resolve<IZmqService>("faceMatchCaptureService"))
                       )
                   );
```

and it worked fine. I am still looking for how to link an interface, view and view-model together. Will post once I find it out.